# Database row is empty

Tags: database, lua, coronasdk

currently my app will create a empty table but with fields, in the future it will be populated by 5 rows, so by default row 1 will be created automatically, what I want is rows 2-5 will be detected as empty. Imagine for every row is representing a button if it has a row the button will be enabled if not, the button will be disabled. I just want to know if how can I know if a row is empty or not

here is my code :

```
--create table
local tblTable = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Testing (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,     boompanes);]]
db:exec(tblTable)


--Insert a value for row 1, rows 2-5 are still empty
local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO Testing Values(null,'1')]]
db:exec(tablefill)

--reads database
for row in db:nrows([[SELECT * FROM Testing WHERE id = '2']]) do
   a=a+1
   print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"..row.id.."\n\n\n\n\n\n")
     if row.id == nil then

        pak = display.newText("CURRENTLY NIL", 100,200, native.font, 32)
        pak:setFillColor(1,0,0)
        pak.y = pak.y+50*a

    else

        kap = display.newText("NOT NIL", 200,300, native.font, 32)
        kap:setFillColor(0,1,0)
        kap.y = kap.y+50*a
    end

end
```

in the console, it doesn't return a nil value it just returns nothing to me

Comment: Corona uses Sqlite, no? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column may not contain NULL. You should let the PK be non-null, and test if one of the other record fields ('boompanes') is empty or nil.

Comment: Where do you initialise/define `a`? How do you run this, can it be that error messages are quietly discarded? (try with `error("foo")` in line 1 if unsure)

Comment: There are no errors, it just returns nothing to me

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to test your SQLite database is to use SQLite Manager extension for Firefox.  You can then load the file (you'll have to find it within the depths of the Corona SDK project files).  But you'll be able to open it in that extension and see what is happening in your database a bit more easier.

This isn't really a solution to your specific problem but it might help you and others.